# Concerns about "have yet to"

Tags: word-meaning

> Ashya King's parents have been freed from Spanish custody after prosecutors withdrew a European arrest warrant. Brett and Naghemeh King were detained after taking five-year-old Ashya, who has a brain tumour, from a Southampton hospital against medical advice. UK prosecutors said they were happy any risk to Ashya's life "was not as great or immediate as... originally thought". Despite being released from custody, Mr and Mrs King **have yet to** leave prison, the BBC understands.

1. What does **have yet to** mean?
2. Does its meaning is a fixed meaning in any other context?
3. Is it about grammar or idiom or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [have yet to (do something)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/have-yet-to-do-something-).

Answer (score 2):

It's used to describe something that has not occurred, but is expected to. In your example the phrase is used to emphasize the previously given information that the Kings have been "released from custody". Obviously since they've been released they will be leaving, they just have not done so yet.

**Examples:**

1.

> The moon has yet to rise tonight.

2.

> User5036 has yet to understand this phrase's meaning, but he will.

3.

> I have yet to post this answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Has yet to" is a fixed phrase that means "still hasn't." It gently implies that the action is expected in the future.

Its use here is not particularly context-dependent. The same phrase can be used in most cases, though it's a little formal to my ear.

It's idiomatic in that it's not assembled from words in their usual format. *Have* and *yet* can be used in several ways each, but *have yet to* isn't a simple combination of any of them.