# Something await someone was yet ... ahead

Tags: word-meaning

[Saint Odd](https://www.amazon.com.br/Saint-Odd-Thomas-Novel/dp/081299910X)

> Alone in the vastness of the Mojave, at two o’clock in the morning,
>   racing along at seventy miles per hour, I felt safe and believed that
>   whatever terror might await me **was yet** many miles ahead. This would
>   not be the first time in my strange life that safety proved to be an
>   illusion.

I don't understand

> whatever terror might await me was yet many miles ahead.

That might means

> I was being surrounded by something terror. I felt safe because if I ran
>   another "many miles", I could escape from the terror.

It doesn't duplicate with "have yet to", because it doesn't have a "have" here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concerns about "have yet to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/concerns-about-have-yet-to)

Answer (score 1):

This means that the terror is many miles ahead. Not that he feels he can outrun it.It's similar to saying:

> I believed that whatever terror might await me was yet to come.

Comment: Then, what's the difference between being with the "yet" and being without the "yet"?

Comment: It's just another way of saying: whatever terror might await me was many miles ahead. I would interpret that he's not worrying about it right this second though.

Comment: Thanks. It's so simple. I just repeatedly looped up it 2 days ...

Comment: Sometimes you may just think too long on something and it just confuses the matter more!